# How to fix "Third-party code blocked the main thread for" in blogger?

Tags: performance, blogger

I use blogger platform on my websites:https://www.mahmul.com/ and https://www.ahlteb.com/ and I'm working on website's speed on Google speed insights, but I usually find that error when checking any link of my website:

"Reduce the impact of third-party code Third-party code blocked the main thread for 560 ms
Third-party code can significantly impact load performance. Limit the number of redundant third-party providers and try to load third-party code after your page has primarily finished loading. Learn more".
[image]
I need to know how to solve this problem and how to remove blogger's unused scripts.
I also need to remove the error of "Analytics code" because when I remove the script from the template, analytics stop though I place the tracking code in blogger settings.

Any help please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Blogger's javascript file can't be removed. It's because whatever your template may contain, ultimately **Blogger** or **Google** serves the content. I'm not sure why they use it but surely it has something to do with their work. Basically, every **Blogger** blog gets served with that javascript. In other words, you don't have full control over your Blogger blog (in fact, no one has!)